# Как вывести определенное количество цифр в Python 3.7? Например: вместо 3.0 => 3.000

Tags: python, python-3.x

Использовал такую функцию, как: .toFixed(). Больше ничего не нашел. Очень нужно.

Comment: `'%.<кол-во цифр>f' % (число)`, пример: `'%.3f' %(3)` будет `3.000`

Comment: А `round(number[, ndigits])` уже не работает?

Comment: @V.March, ну как-бы, `round(3, 3)` буде все-таки 3, а не 3.000

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
n = 3.0
print(f'{n:.3f}')

# 3.000
```

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 3
n = format(n, '.3f')
print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Либо так:

```
>>> '%.3f' % (3)
3.000
```